# camel-bindy - How do I define if there are no body records during unmarshaling and marshaling

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I have some records in files.
There are header, body, and footer.
In the some case, the file has all three type records.
but, the file has only header and footer in another case.

I want to parse these file by using same data format.

Data Defined. (body)

```
@FixedLengthRecord(header=KRHeader.class, footer=KRTrailer.class)
public class KRFixedFormat implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @DataField(pos=1, length=1, trim=true)
    private String sType; 
    ....
```

Data Defined. (header)

```
@FixedLengthRecord(length=39, paddingChar=' ')
public class KRHeader implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @DataField(pos=1, length=1, trim=true, defaultValue="H")
    private String sType; 
    ....
```

Data Defined. (Footer)

```
@FixedLengthRecord(length=44, paddingChar=' ')
public class KRTrailer implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@DataField(pos=1, length=1, trim=true, defaultValue="T")
private char sType;
    ....
```

If the file with only header and footer is cooming, application has generated exception like blow.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No records have been defined in the file
at org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.fixed.BindyFixedLengthDataFormat.unmarshal(BindyFixedLengthDataFormat.java:250) ~[camel-bindy-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
at org.apache.camel.processor.UnmarshalProcessor.process(UnmarshalProcessor.java:69) ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548) ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
```

How do we implement to meet our business requirement?

Comment: I dont think I have heard about such a requirement before that the data is empty. You would need to check this yourself as a workaround for now I would think. So what would you have as output since the body is empty

Comment: The output of this requirement about body is empty is raw data with header and footer. But the exception is generated at current implementation.
I want to find a solution to handle these exception in this case, not normal IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: There are options about header/footer in FixedLengthRecord clause.
(ex. isHeader, isFooter, skipFooter, and etc.)
Like this, is option about body?

Comment: I found annotation about csv format.
https://github.com/apache/camel/pull/1521/commits/36df913f53e5a211f83171c86750ae3299b27df1
Is a option like this about FixedLengthFormat?

Comment: Yeah that is a good idea. I have logged a ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-13392. You are welcome to implement this and contribute this to the Apache Camel project